# Group/Sum/Divide distribute data in foreach loop php

Tags: php

I have some issues with this code i made to group and substract the stores with priority to make a sale, what i want to do is to look in each store but first to have a look in the prioritized store_id, then if not keep looking in other stores until i reach the quantity requested, if in the quanity is distributed in more than 1 store i need to divide the product and get the quantities until i reach all quantities requested.

The data with products requested and stock information

```
 $data = array(
                    array(
                        'product_id' => 65676,
                        'quantity' => 10,
                        'stock' => array(
                            array(
                                'product_id'    => 65676,
                                'store_id'      => 1,
                                'qty'           => 3,

                            ),
                            array(
                                'product_id'    => 65676,
                                'store_id'      => 2,
                                'qty'           => 3
                            ),
                            array(
                                'product_id'    => 65676,
                                'store_id'      => 3,
                                'qty'           => 8
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'product_id' => 34742,
                        'quantity' => 3,
                        'stock' => array(
                            array(
                                'product_id'    => 34742,
                                'store_id'      => 3,
                                'qty'           => 5
                            ),
                            array(
                                'product_id'    => 34742,
                                'store_id'      => 2,
                                'qty'           => 5
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                );
```

Function to extract the priority store id

```
    function searchForIdDefaultStore($store_id, $array) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                if ($val['store_id'] === $store_id) {
                    return $key;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The job to group by product_id

```
            echo '<pre>';

            /* I need to have a prioritar store */
            /* I need to group by product_id and store_id so if all items are in the same store i need to send to that store */
            $storePrioritar = 1;
            foreach($data as $dat){
                $arrayItems[] = $dat['product_id']; //May i check with this if all items i passe trough exist in new array.
                $getKey = $this->searchForIdDefaultStore($storePrioritar, $dat['stock']); //Get prioritar store_id
                if(!is_null($getKey)){
                    //If the quantity in store_id is bigger or equal than requested.
                    if($dat['stock'][$getKey]['qty'] >= $dat['quantity']){
                        $grouped[$dat['product_id']][] = array(
                            'product_id'    => $dat['product_id'],
                            'store_id'      => $dat['stock'][$getKey]['store_id'],
                            'neeQty'        => $dat['quantity'],
                            'haveQty'       => $dat['stock'][$getKey]['qty']
                        );
                    }else{
                        //If not i will loop over all stores and get there where i foudn the item.
                        foreach($dat['stock'] as $stock){
                            if($stock['product_id'] == $dat['product_id']){
                                //If the quantity is bigger or equal than requested
                                if($stock['qty'] >= $dat['quantity']){
                                    $grouped[$stock['product_id']][] = array(
                                        'product_id'    => $dat['product_id'],
                                        'store_id'      => $stock['store_id'],
                                        'neeQty'        => $dat['quantity'],
                                        'haveQty'       => $stock['qty']
                                    );
                                }else{
                                    //If not just give me what is available
                                    $grouped[$stock['product_id']][] = array(
                                        'product_id'    => $dat['product_id'],
                                        'store_id'      => $stock['store_id'],
                                        'neeQty'        => $dat['quantity'],
                                        'haveQty'       => $stock['qty']
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{ //If i have no prioritar i will group by product_id
                    foreach($dat['stock'] as $stock){
                        if($stock['product_id'] == $dat['product_id']){
                            //If the quantity is bigger or equal than requested
                            if($stock['qty'] >= $dat['quantity']){
                                $grouped[$stock['product_id']][] = array(
                                    'product_id'    => $dat['product_id'],
                                    'store_id'      => $stock['store_id'],
                                    'neeQty'        => $dat['quantity'],
                                    'haveQty'       => $stock['qty']
                                );
                            }else{
                                //If not just give me what is available
                                $grouped[$stock['product_id']][] = array(
                                    'product_id'    => $dat['product_id'],
                                    'store_id'      => $stock['store_id'],
                                    'neeQty'        => $dat['quantity'],
                                    'haveQty'       => $stock['qty']
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            print_r($grouped);
    /* The problem now is that i have 2 Products ID with stock and i need to group and substract the quantity if the requested quantity is not enough in that store */

    My question is, how can i group and sum/rest divide for each store in one loop ?
```

The result i expect is:

```
array(
            1 => array(
                    array(
                        'product_id'    => 65676,
                        'store_id'      => 1,
                        'quantity'      => 2,
                    )
            ),
            3 => array(
                    array(
                        'product_id'    => 65676,
                        'store_id'      => 3,
                        'quantity'      => 8,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'product_id'    => 34742,
                        'store_id'      => 3,
                        'quantity'      => 3,
                    )
            )
        )
        Note: the key is the store_id
```

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Comment: Hello @RomanPerekhrest , i have added the result i expect to the question. Thx